# Is there a good way to update committer email addresses in bzr?

Tags: bazaar

Is there a good way to update committer email addresses in bzr?  Using the fastimport plugin, I can do something like:

```
bzr fast-export --no-plain ./trunk/ trunk.fi
cat trunk.fi | bzr fast-import-filter--user-map=names.txt > trunk_clean.fi
bzr init fixed
bzr fast-import trunk_clean.fi ./fixed
```

What concerns me about this approach is that I'm worried that my branches won't be properly associated with the filtered trunk.  As such, is there a better way to update committer email addresses?  If I need to use fastimport, is there a way to do so where all the branches I care about are still associated with one another in the history?

Answer (score 0):

Use `whoami` like this:

```
bzr whoami "Firstname Lastname <email.address@example.com>"
```

Email addresses can also be set by branch in the config file:

```
vi $HOME/.bazaar/branches.conf

[/some/branch/location]
email=Your Name <name@other-isp.com>
```

**References**

- [Setting email via the 'whoami' command](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrSettingEmail)
- [PEP 374](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0374/)

Comment: And this will also change the email address is old commits?